# Batch - Can't seem to read a CSV file

Tags: csv, parsing, batch-file

I have no issues with text files, but when I try to do something simple with a csv, it doesn't work!

The csv can be found here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!At4HWeqiFYNvhuo4ibcifbvPwO_4wA

```
Name,Type,Value,Designate,Access,Source,Description,Restricted,Unit Quantity,Unit
TITLE_1,String,PCB ASSY,Yes,Full,User-Defined,,,,
```

code:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%FILENAME%) DO (
    Set FileLine=%%a
    echo !FileLine!
)
```

Can someone please help! Thank you!

Comment: what is the problem? do you want to print the fields, or just the line?

Comment: Please show more of your batch. We cannot tell from what you've posted what state your `cmd` session has established. What is your actual filename? Is the file in your current directory? What response are you getting that you don't expect? What "doesn't work?"

Comment: Currently I can't even echo the lines, Once I can read the lines, I can process it. Just set your FILENAME variable to where you downloaded the file. You can add: 
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion. That is it!

Comment: Please use the file in the link, as this is a partial output of another system and if there is any encoding issues, I would like to know.

Comment: Please embed (an excerpt of) the CSV file into your question rather than just providing a link to some external resource, so the question remains complete in future and the risk of insufficient access privileges is eliminated...

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ says your file was encoded in UCS2 LE with BOM.  I changed the encoding to ANSI and your code worked.  For what it's worth, the `type` command seems to be more tolerant of that encoding and byte order mark.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set "file=param_table.csv"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('type "%file%"') do (
    set "line=%%I"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to change the encoding using batch? This file is an export from another program and I would need it to be done automatically.

Comment: @Wajo357 Well, I tried `chcp 65001` to change the console codepage to Unicode, but that didn't allow the `for /f` loop to read the contents natively.  PowerShell will be more tolerant than batch for this sort of processing.  From the console, `powershell "gc param_table.csv | %{ \"line: $_\" }"` outputs as expected.  Indeed, powershell would make it easy to deserialize the csv text into an object, and would perhaps offer a more graceful solution.  Try `powershell "ipcsv param_table.csv"`

Comment: Thank you. I have not really done much with powershell. How can I go through each line at a time to look for certain values? Can I export this back out as a text file?

Comment: The powershell "ipcsv param_table.csv" does look good. If I can export that to a text file for processing, that would be awesome!

Comment: ehh... that was easy. I just did powershell "ipcsv param_table.csv">file.txt

Comment: Rojo, I ran into a scenario where the powershell is not converting the csv file properly. I have changed the link above to the new file. You can also see it here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!At4HWeqiFYNvhuo4ibcifbvPwO_4wA . The value should be "0.156"LS, STRGHT, W/ LOCK RAMP" but the forward slash seems to screw with this. Any help? Thank you so much!

Comment: sorry... it is the quote and the commas in the value that seem to mess with this. The quote seems to end the value in powershell and the commas move it to the next field.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issues as rojo, just to show parsing with `delims=,` here my batch

```
@Echo off
Set FileNAme=".\param_table.csv"
Echo whole lines
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type %FILENAME%') DO (
    Set FileLine=%%a
    echo !FileLine!
)
Echo:
Echo split into fields/columns reversed order
for /f "tokens=1-10 delims=," %%a in ('type %FILENAME%') DO (
    echo %%j,%%i,%%h,%%g,%%f,%%e,%%d,%%c,%%b,%%a
)
```

output

```
whole lines
Name,Type,Value,Designate,Access,Source,Description,Restricted,Unit Quantity,Unit
TITLE_1,String,PCB ASSY,Yes,Full,User-Defined,,,,

split into fields/columns reversed order
Unit,Unit Quantity,Restricted,Description,Source,Access,Designate,Value,Type,Name
,,,,User-Defined,Full,Yes,PCB ASSY,String,TITLE_1
```

My hex vbscript show this:

```
Detected Byte Order Mark (BOM) : UTF16LE

Blk00000: File : param_table.csv
HexOffs.:_+0_+1_+2_+3__+4_+5_+6_+7__+8_+9_+A_+B__+C_+D_+E_+F__----____----____
00000000: FF FE 4E 00  61 00 6D 00  65 00 2C 00  54 00 79 00  ..N.a.m.e.,.T.y.
00000010: 70 00 65 00  2C 00 56 00  61 00 6C 00  75 00 65 00  p.e.,.V.a.l.u.e.
00000020: 2C 00 44 00  65 00 73 00  69 00 67 00  6E 00 61 00  ,.D.e.s.i.g.n.a.
00000030: 74 00 65 00  2C 00 41 00  63 00 63 00  65 00 73 00  t.e.,.A.c.c.e.s.
00000040: 73 00 2C 00  53 00 6F 00  75 00 72 00  63 00 65 00  s.,.S.o.u.r.c.e.
```

Comment: so you also converted the file?

Comment: Not explicitly,  type does the conversion by itself. `param_table.csv` is still in your original format see appended hex otuput in my answer.

Comment: I can't use something like iconv?

Comment: I don't see what you are aiming at. If you want to keep the file in UTF16LE batch isn't the ideal choice. If you are well with the conversion type does this is ok. you could convert the file prior running the batch on it and type will still deal with the file. Problem is when the conversion to cp1252 or cp850 will result in a loss of chars not available in these code pages.

Comment: I am using a mapkey from another software to export the csv and then trigger the batch. There will be no point where manual intervention will be available. Especially since this will be done by other users. I would like to automate the process.

Comment: @Wajo357 Well till now you didn't expand on that (better use a new question) The reason your batch didn't work is cleared and Kudos (vote up and/or checked answer) should go to rojo as he was the first to detect this.

Answer (score 0):

I also used

```
powershell "get-content !CSVFileName!" >!TXTFileName!
```

to just convert the exact file without reformatting it. I was therefore able to account for any parsing issues when there were commas, colons, quotes within the values themselves; in my own code.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Rojo, I am using

```
powershell "ipcsv !CSVFileName!" >!TXTFileName!
```

Comment: Pretty sure it was Rojo who helped you.